# Send email with material from tableview or NSmutableDictionary

Tags: ios, email, nsdictionary

In my app, I have a tableView whose material is from my NSmutableDictionary. When I push a button, I want to send these material to a email.Here is the code for sending email:

```
//Below to send email
- (IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender {
    // Email Subject
    NSString *emailTitle = @"Course Planner of iBcChem";
    // Email Content
    NSString *messageBody = @"Please check my course plan";
    // To address
    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"xxxxx@gmail.com"];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];//want to fix here
    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Here is my question:

How can I add my material to the `messageBody` please? Can I use the method similar to show my dictionary like below in my `messageBody` please?

```
NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", [_sectionContents description]);//test dictionary here
```

Where `_sectionContents` is my dictionary.

Comment: Simply append the dictionary data as desired to `messageBody`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any example I can look at please?

Comment: There's plenty of examples. Search on using `NSMutableString` or using `NSString stringWithFormat:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach you dictionary by the same code which you have written.

Here is the code for you.

```
NSString *emailTitle = @"Course Planner of iBcChem";
NSString *messageBody = @"Please check my course plan";
NSDictionary *dci = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B", nil]];
NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"xxxxx@gmail.com"];

MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];


mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc setSubject:emailTitle];
[mc setMessageBody:dci.description isHTML:NO];
[mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

In simulator mail delegate will take some time to load the Body part of mailcomposersheet. The body will look like.

```
{
    A = 1;
    B = 2;
}
```

Enjoy Coding !!